# Detecting Taps on a subview in UIScrollView *and* ignoring pan gestures

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have displaying image thumbnails in a `UIScrollView`, if user taps on a thumbnail, the application should open that image. if, however, user drags on a thumb, the scroll view should pan. Right now the scrollview only scrolls if user is able to drag on the small empty space between the thumbnails. the subviews (the one's displaying image thumbs) use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to detect taps, and `exclusiveTouch` on subviews is set to `NO`, `UIScrollView` has its `canCancelContentTouches` set to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try leaving `canCancelContentTouches` set to YES, that allows the scroll view to override its subviews if it seems the user is trying to scroll.